# Using django prefetch_related in sqlite

Tags: django, sqlite, django-orm

I have a model which is related with other model.

```
class Foo(...)
 ...

class Bar(...)
 foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name('bars'))
```

I need to load all related Bars for many Foos so I use prefetch_related.

```
Foo.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('bars')
```

In debug_toolbar I see additional query which takes Bars for all foos, but there are also queries which takes Bars for every single Foo.

Doesn't prefetch_related work in sqlite? Or am I doing something wrong?

I iterate through all Foos in template, but I think this does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in my code. I used latest() method in my manager which executed another query.